# If I make a payment on fiverr and it uses paypal, how can I control which card is used?

Tags: paypal

If I make a payment on fiverr and it uses paypal, how can I control which card is used?

It tends to just pick a particular card.

Comment: [Payment Methods:](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/popup/about-payment-methods) *availability of payment methods may be limited based on particular seller you are using to complete the transaction*  [PayPal Support:](https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/contact-us) **Message Us** and **Call Us** buttons prominently displayed on this page, and best way to get support.

Comment: @BlindSpots i've asked them  multiple times, they have no clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to deal with the paypal situation, you can go to your fiverr account and "remove" your paypal account from there. Then, when you buy, you just get sent to paypal like you would normally. And you choose the card you want to use.

The problem I was facing was I think that fiverr has some feature for faster checkout that does some shortcut with paypal and doesn't let you choose a card. You can stop it doing that by "removing" the listing of paypal account within the settings of your fiverr account.

I think that solves it, based on a recent test.

BTW, apparently they have some support for google wallet on android so that might be worth looking at.

**ADDED**

I've figured it out the process. You have to go to  profile.."billing and payments" (which is below where it says "settings")

[image]

Then  "payment methods"

[image]

And it hneeds to look like this i.e. no payment methods set.

If you then make a payment, you have the choice to use paypal and it lets you choose which card to use.

Then, be aware that immediately after having done that payment, it will have added paypal under payment methods and will default to a particular card in paypal next time. So you have to remove that paypal entry from "payment methods", before making the next payment. Then, when you make that next payment, you can choose the card.

So, clear the payment methods(if not already clear), make  the paypal payment, and then clear the payment methods! That's the process

Comment: I would have expected that the API would select the default payment method.  Fiver may be able to (although I'm surprised) choose from available payment methods.  If that is the case, they would know their costs by option and could favor lower-cost options.

Comment: @BlindSpots the answer I posted is a solution, there's no point discussing the problem mentioned in the question, on my answer. If you want to discuss the problem, then you should comment on the question not on this answer

Comment: @BlindSpots The answer I posted is a solution, there's no point discussing the problem mentioned in the question, on my answer. If you want to discuss the problem, then you should comment on the question not on this answe.  Aside from that your comment about "lower-cost options" makes no sense and shows a misunderstanding of the situation, which is now solved anyway.